# Can't pass property from parent element to react-select component

Tags: reactjs, refs, react-select

I'm trying to pass property to react-select element from other component but I get following error

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded

I lookup online and fb documentation regading the error here https://gist.github.com/jimfb/4faa6cbfb1ef476bd105

And tried the possible solutions, but still did not fix the issue.

I'm using `react` ver `15.1` and the `react-select` is in `1.00 beta` version

Here's the sample code:

In my `app.js`:

```
var options = [
    { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
    { value: 'two', label: 'Two' }
];

function logChange(val) {
    console.log("Selected: " + val);
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <some.myDiv><span><some.ffff
    options={options}
    onChange={logChange}
    key={5}

  /></span></some.myDiv>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

In my `resuable.js`:

```
window.some = {

  "ffff":React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (<Select


    {...this.props}
  />);
        }
    }),
    myDiv:React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (<div


    {...this.props}
  />);
        }
    }),

}
```

Comment: Why is it that you're adding your component to *window.some*?

Comment: that's just an exapmle...I'm not using correct module import or export! So, as an alternative storing all my reusable components in one `window variable`

Comment: I've never actually seen components with composed names, like `<some.ffff />`. Don't even know if that's supposed to work, either.

Comment: yep that will work..it's working for other components which I created but, isn't working only for `Select` which is imported from `react-select`

Comment: Does it work if you swap yours with `Select` and `div` directly? The `some.x` shouldn't be the problem here, but `{...this.props}` might. If anything taking a bit of extra time to create a jsbin could help others help you debug this.

Comment: i had the same issue because of multiple copies of react. i fixed it by upgrading `npm to ^3.0.0` and then reinstalling `node_modules`.